# How to speed up the usb drives?

Tags: usb, usb-drive, administration, file-transfer

Lately I'm using usb 2.0 drives to move things around,in order to free a bit of local traffic, but unfortunately it takes so much time to write things.

A first approach is to use a no sync feature on fstab based on the UUID; but this carry the risk of data losing if (by whatever reason) the write isn't done immediately,so  there is a realiable method to speed up (even a bit) the write on an usb flash drive?

Comment: You probably can't. USB 2 is fairly limited in speed as a protocol and it's unlikely that the flash in your drive is the bottleneck for writes. What speed are you getting?

Comment: It starts at 5MB more or less, but later it drops to the order of kB, i.e. I move chunks of 5GB it takes more than an hour to make the write, the mass is made of files of variable size, so since Im using a gui there is no reliable way to make a benchmark, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: As a workaround was thinking of using a microSD class 10, I have had better results in the past, but right know Its a bit hard to make me with several units, and besides the devices that receive the info dont have a microsd slot. So it is still worth the test for speed up a bit via usb.

Comment: I found this commands but I dont understand if this is safe to do echo $((16*1024*1024)) > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_bytes echo $((48*1024*1024)) > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_bytes